# Formal Proof For Rational Function Limit with a Quadratic in the denominator

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta, rational-functions

I've been trying my hand at a another practice problem for my first-year differential calculus class, but I cannot seem to make it past a certain step. The problem is as follows:

Let $f(x)=\frac{-x}{(x+4)^2}$. Using a formal proof, prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to -4}f(x)=\infty$.

From my own prior understanding, the definition of a limit tending to infinity is as follows (roughly):

Given $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$, for every $M>0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $f(x)>M$.

Here is my attempt at the problem (I am currently stuck on deriving the relationship between $\delta$ and $M$)

Let $M>0$ be given. Suppose $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Then we have $0<|x+4|<\delta$.

And so, $\frac{1}{(x+4)^2}>\frac{1}{\delta^2}$

Taking a look at our initial inequality, we have $0<|x+4|$ and so $x>-4$ or $x<-4$. Using $x<-4$, we have $-x>4$.

By $\frac{1}{(x+4)^2}>\frac{1}{\delta^2}$, it should follow that $\frac{-x}{(x+4)^2}>\frac{4}{\delta^2}=M$ and so $\delta=\frac{2}{\sqrt{M}}$.

Using this value for $\delta$, we can thus formulate a proper proof. However, that's not my question. My question is, is my derivation for the relationship between $\delta$ and $M$ correct? Is something that I am forgetting to account for, because when I go and graph the appropriate inequalities and equation using graphing software, there are some values for $x$ such that if $|x+4|<delta$ then $f(x)<M$, which shouldn't occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We cannot "choose to use" $x > -4$ or $x<-4$. We should account for them both. One way to do that is to fix $\delta < 1$. Then $-x > 3$.

Comment: @player3236 Thank you for your help. I just want to ask, how were you able to go from having $\delta<1$ to then having $-x>3$? I also presume, that fixing $\delta<1$ makes it so $\delta_M=\min\{1,?\}$ where $?$ will be the relationship I derive between $\delta$ and $M$.

Comment: Indeed. From $0 < |x+4| < \delta < 1$ we have $-1 < x+4< 1$. This gives $-5 < x < -3$.

Comment: @player3236 Yes, that makes much more sense, thank you. Just one last clarification, we use the $x<-3$ part of the inequality rather than $x>-5$ since both account for $x>-4$ and $x<-4$ and the former works with our inequality $\frac{1}{(x+4)^2}>\frac{1}{\delta^2}$ when multiplied by $-1$?

Comment: A couple of points re player3236's comment, which I think *nailed* the situation:  (1) he used integers to make analysis easier (2) with experience you will realize that in a situation like this, **before** you can set up an $\delta, M$ relationship, you **must** arbitrarily set some fixed range for the numerator.  The intuition behind this is that by fixing the range of the numerator, you have established a relationship between $\frac{|3|}{\delta^2}, \frac{|5|}{\delta^2},$ and $M$.

Comment: @player3236 I'm sorry again for bothering you, but this is the first time I've used a formal proof where $\delta$ is the minimum of two values. Using your advice, I have $\delta = \min\{1, \sqrt{\frac{3}{M}}\}$. I'm having trouble determining how to incorporate both the $1$ and the $\sqrt{\frac{3}{M}}$ in the proof. Is it that I use the $1$ to have $0<|x+4|<\delta$ to get $0<|x+4|<\delta<1$ and eventually $-5<x<-3$ from which I'll use the $x<-3$ to show that $\frac{-x}{(x+4)^2}>\frac{3}{\delta^2}$ to which I'll incorporate $\sqrt{\frac{3}{M}}$ to show $f(x)>M$? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: Yes. Using $\min$ allows you to choose an upper bound to $\delta$ whenever you want.